# Hide Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Working With Android Framgent,I having Three fragments layout i want to hide fragment on the basis of flag.When First fragment is visible want disable second fragment
Am successfully able to hide tab headings of tab layout but not able to remove Page.How to achive it.?
I have searched alot but didn't find as i accepted.

```
public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity implements Commands.FragmentDataListener_Commands_epg{
Bundle dataBundle;
TabLayout tabLayout;
String flag;
private Sample.SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private GoogleApiClient client;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_customer);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    flag = intent.getStringExtra("flag");

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new Sample.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    if(flag.equals("1")) {
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(0);

    }
    else if(flag.equals("2"))
    {
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(1);
    }

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}


@Override
public void onFragmentDataUpdated(Bundle dataBundle)
{
    this.dataBundle=dataBundle;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                    //first page
            case 1:
                    //second page
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "First";
            case 1:
                return "second";
          }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you get the flag in intent, you don't need tabLayout. Just init and the fragment to your view.
Some code like below:

```
Fragment fragmentInput = new  FragmentAddVehicle();
FragmentManager  getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.ll_root_container, fragmentInput).commit();
```

Comment: I want to hide layout not add

Comment: In the onCreate, setup the fragment array and use its size for your getCount() of SectionsPagerAdapter. Then no tab remove needed.